# StaggeredGridView setAdapter after addHeaderView and addFooterView

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-custom-view, staggered-gridview

I try to use StaggeredGridView in my new applicaiton. Everything is working fine. Now i want to add a HeaderView and a FooterView, but this gives me following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ExtendableListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ExtendableListView(2131165194, class com.tundem.numbersreloaded.view.NumbersGridView) with Adapter(class com.etsy.android.grid.HeaderViewListAdapter)]
            at com.etsy.android.grid.ExtendableListView.layoutChildren(ExtendableListView.java:557)
            at com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView.layoutChildren(StaggeredGridView.java:358)
            at com.etsy.android.grid.ExtendableListView.onLayout(ExtendableListView.java:513)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I set the Adapter in the onPostExecute method of an AsynchTask which has it's onExecute method in the onCreate of my Activity.
I also add the Header and FooterView in the onCreateMethod before i start the AsynchTask.

I've also tried to run it from the runOnUiThread and i've also checked via Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper() if i'm in the UI Thread. Anyone with hints how i can solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer already on my own.

It was not my issue i had all the time. It's a issue the AndroidStaggeredGrid currently has.
There's already a merged Pull-Request with a fix but it was no uploaded to maven yet.

I refer to those two commits:

- https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid/commit/18e9ae8251ff30ae29125613c8fd909e5e8c27a6
- https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid/commit/2fce475c197bb18871d2a1076e259a57d8513104

For now the solution is to build the library on your own and publish it to a private maven repo, or you include the project as library project!

Comment: Is this fixed in the latest etsy version? I still have this crash in my app and I do not think there is an issue with my code.

Comment: @MikeT i assume not yet. But you can use the StaggeredLayoutManager which is now included in Android with the RecyclerView

Comment: Last time I used this slm, I had some strange sideeffects, but thanx for the idea, I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling adapter.notifiyDataSetChanged() in the onPostExecute method of your AsyncTask?

This order is working for me:

- Add header and footer view in your onCreate method, then set the adapter, then execute Async Task
- In the onPostExecute method of your AsyncTask you add all items to your adapter (addAll or add depending on SDK Version) and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Thanks. i tried this already.
I've found the answer in the meantime. will post it as soon as i'm allowed to answer my own question.